# Assembly (MASM) quickSort

Tags: assembly, masm32

So I have been working on this procedure for a few days now. It seems to works only sometimes, the rest of the time I get a stack overflow error when I run it in VS. 
My program generates random numbers in a range 100 to 999 in to an array, the size of which is inputed by user (max size 200), which is what I declared my array size as. After which I use my quickSort proc, here is the code

```
;-------------------------------------------------------
sortList PROC
; Sets up call to quickSort by calculating size of array,
; then passing high, low, and @array as arugments.
; Receives: @array: PTR DWORD   ; reference to array
;           req:DWORD           ; value of the requested number
; Returns:  nothing
;-------------------------------------------------------
enter   0,0                 

mov     eax, [ebp+12]   ; value of request
mov     ecx, 4          ; size of each element in the array
mul     ecx             ; multiplied to get sizeof the array
mov     ebx, eax        ; ebx = size of array
sub     ebx, 4          ; sub 4 for starting address last element
mov     eax, 0          ; zero eax for beginning element
mov     esi, [ebp+8]    ; @array

push    ebx             ; high
push    eax             ; low
push    esi             ; @array
call    quickSort

pop     ebx             ; restore ebx
pop     eax             ; restore eax
pop     esi             ; restore esi
leave
ret 8
sortList ENDP

;-------------------------------------------------------
quickSort PROC
; Uses recursion to sort the array.
; Receives: @arr: PTR DWORD     ; reference to array
;           LEFT:DWORD          ; value of beg index
;           RIGHT:DWORD         ; value of end index
; Returns:  nothing
; Adapted from: Algorithm implemented in C
; http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort
;-------------------------------------------------------
LOCAL   right:DWORD,        ; high value of array
        left:DWORD          ; low value of array

mov     eax, [ebp+12]   ; Value of low into eax
mov     left, eax       ; left = low
mov     ebx, [ebp+16]   ; Value of high into ebx
mov     right, ebx      ; right = high
mov     esi, [ebp+8]    ; @array

mov     edi, [esi]      ; edi = pivot
mov     eax, left       ; eax = i
mov     ebx, right      ; ebx = j

mainLoop:
cmp     eax, ebx        ; Loop while i <= j
jg      endMain
iCheck:
cmp     [esi+eax], edi  ; Loop while array[i] > pivot
jle     endiCheck
add     eax, 4
jmp     iCheck
endiCheck:

jCheck:
cmp     [esi+ebx], edi  ; Loop while array[j] < pivot
jge     endjCheck
sub     ebx, 4          ; move to array[j-1]
jmp     jCheck
endjCheck:

cmp     eax, ebx        ; If i <= j, swap the places in the array
jg      endSwap
; Using stack properties to perform swap
push    [esi+eax]
push    [esi+ebx]
pop     [esi+eax]
pop     [esi+ebx]

add     eax, 4          ; increment i
sub     ebx, 4          ; decrement j
endSwap:
jmp     mainLoop
endMain:
mov     ecx, right          ; restore right index into ecx
mov     edx, left           ; restore left index into edx
Lrecursion:
cmp     edx, ebx        ; Compare left to j
jge     Rrecursion      ; If left < j, then call quickSort again
push    ebx             ; high value of left half
push    edx             ; low value of left half 
push    esi             ; @array 
call    quickSort

Rrecursion:
cmp     eax, ecx        ; Compare i to right
jge     theEnd          ; If i < right, call quickSort
push    ecx             ; high value of right half
push    eax             ; low value of right half
push    esi             ; @array
call    quickSort

theEnd:
ret     12

quickSort ENDP
```

After stepping through with the breakpoints in the debugger I think there is a logic error I am missing. I input an array of three. The values generated were 472 108 988. My code correctly put 988 in place, but once it got to sorting the last two it was not able to resolve.
A pointer in the right direction would be much appreciated. I hope I came across clear. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Exactly what does _"it was not able to resolve"_ mean? And why is `sortList` popping the registers in the same order as it pushed them? Also, what about when `call quickSort` under `Lrecursion` returns? If the `call quickSort` under `Rrecursion` also gets called you will have pushed 24 bytes onto the stack, but it looks like you only pop 12.

Comment: Didn't get far enough to check logic and algorithm, but your work with stack is flawed left/right/pretty much everywhere. Like at start of `quickSort PROC` you don't set up `ebp`, but you use it to work with stack frame, or the `sortList` tries to restore values from stack, which were not push there, etc... I wonder how this can do even something reasonable when testing, IMO it should be unable to even return properly.

Comment: @Michael the quickSort ends with `ret 12`, so the three `push` ahead of `call` are removed by `ret`, those 3 `pop` are actually loading old `ebp`, return address, and something what was on stack before calling `sortList`.

Comment: @Pe7g `ENTER 0,0 ` does the work of `push ebp` `mov ebp, esp` and `sub esp, numbytes` then `LEAVE` pops ebp. But thanks I will look into my stack work more

Comment: @H.W.D yes, but you don't have `enter` in `quickSort` procedure, only in `sortList`.

Comment: `enter` is really slow, and not worth using.  `leave` is ok, but compilers never use `enter.

Answer (score 0):

MASM has prologue and epilogue macros that respond to PROC keyword, so;

```
quickSort PROC @arr:PTR DWORD, LEFT:DWORD, RIGHT:DWORD
```

Then the assembler will create a procedure frame probably using

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
add     esp, 0xFFF8           for your locals right & left
```

Then the epilogue macro will automatically calculate the number of bytes passed to PROC and assemble

```
leave
ret     12
```

Similarly

```
mov     esi, [ebp+8]           can be replaced with
mov     esi, [@arr]
```

I don't have MASM32 to prove my contention, but I think it will still decrement ESP by 8 to accomadate the locals, so in essence, each iteration of PROC, ESP is only being incremented by 4. MASM32 can be used without PROC, or even intermixing, but that kind of defeats the purpose of using the macro.